# Gradients of marginal likelihood of Gaussian Process with squared exponential covariance, for learning hyper-parameters

Tags: machine-learning

The derivation of gradient of the marginal likelihood is given in http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf

But the gradient for the most commonly used covariance function, squared exponential covariance, is not explicitly given.

I am implementing the Rprop algorithm in http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/_media/publications/blumesann2013.pdf for learning hyper-parameters sigma (signal variance) and h (length). Alas, my implementation is not working well. I have derived the gradients but I am not sure if they are correct.

Can someone point me to a good tutorial / article that explicitly give the expressions for the hyper parameter gradients?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We are looking to maximise the log probability of $lnP(y|x, \theta)$:

$$\ln P(y|x, \theta) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln|K| - \frac{1}{2}y^tK^{-1}y - \frac{N}{2}\ln{2\pi}$$

The three components can be seen as balancing the complexity of the GP (to avoid overfit) and the data fit, with a constant on the end. So the gradient is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i} \log P(y|x, \theta) = \frac{1}{2}y^TK^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial\theta_i}K^{-1}y^T 
-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left(K^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial\theta_i}\right)$$

So all we need to know is $\frac{\partial K}{\partial\theta_i}$ to be able to solve it. I think you got this far but I wasn't sure so I thought I would recap.

For the case of the RBF/expodentiated quadratic (never call it squared exponential as this is actually incorrect) kernel, under the following formulation:

$$K(x,x') = \sigma^2\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\right)$$

The derivatives with respect to the hyperparameters are as follows:

$$\frac{\partial K}{\partial\sigma} = 2\sigma\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial K}{\partial l} = \sigma^2\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\right) \frac{(x-x')^T(x-x')}{l^3}$$

However, often GP libraries use the notation:

$$K(x,x') = \sigma\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{l}\right)$$

where $\sigma$ and $l$ is confined to only to positive real numbers. Let $l=exp(\theta_1)$ and $\sigma=exp(2\theta_2)$, then by passing in $a,b$ we know are values will conform to this rule. In this case the derivatives are:

$$\frac{\partial K}{\partial\theta_1} = \sigma\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\right)\left(\frac{(x-x')^T(x-x')}{l^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial K}{\partial \theta_2} = 2 \sigma\exp\left(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\right)$$

There is is interesting work carried out by the likes of Mike Osborne looking at marginalising out hyper parameters. However as far as I am aware I think it is only appropriate for low numbers of parameters and isn't incorporated in standard libraries yet. Worth a look all the same.

Another not is that the optimisation space is multimodal the majority of the time so if you are using convex optimisation be sure to use a fare few initialisations.

*Edit from comments: Optimizing multidimensional kernel functions*

To extend the answer based on feedback from the comments, I thought I would also add a note on multidimensional kernel functions. Really, from the perspective of the maths multidimensional kernels are treated like any other by taking the partial derivative of the kernel $K$ with respect to a particular hyper parameter.

A nicety of ARD kernels (kernels with independent kernels for each dimension multiplied together, see [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/cookbook/) for different types of kernels) is that the derivatives come out very easily:

$$K(x,x') = K(x_1,x_1')K(x_2,x_2')K(x_3,x_3')$$

$$\frac{\partial K}{\partial l_1} = \frac{\partial K(x_1,x_1')}{\partial l_1}K(x_2,x_2')K(x_3,x_3')$$

In fact, many kernels (not just multidimensional input) can be created via the addition and multiplication of simple kernel functions, read more on [kernel cookbook](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/cookbook/). This makes the maths for optimisation quite nice as you can simply apply the sum and product rules of derivatives to work out the optimization steps.

Comment: jpro is right, your answer for $\frac{dK}{dl}$ is incorrect

Comment: Ah sorry about that - I'll fix it when I get home not to confuse people in the future

Comment: Why is $dK_{d\theta_1} = \frac{...}{l^2}$, but $dK_{dl} = \frac{...}{l^3}$?

Comment: Could you add the derivatives for individual length-scales when $\Lambda$ is used? Where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with each element representing the length-scale for a specific input dimension.

Comment: @Svalorzen sure, if you wish to take the partial derivative of any parameter of K you can do so (provided it is differentiable).

Comment: @j__ Sorry, I probably was not clear. I was asking whether you'd consider adding to your answer the partial derivatives for individual length scales. I managed to do them myself, but having a nice reference added to your excellent answer would be helpful :)

Answer (score 11):

I believe that the derivative of $\frac{\partial K}{\partial l}$, as it was given by j_f  is not correct. I think that the correct one is the following (i present the derivation step by step):

$K(x,x') = \sigma^2\exp\big(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\big)$
I now call $g(l)=\big(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\big)$. So $K=\sigma^2exp\big( g(l) \big)$.

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial l} = \frac{\partial K}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial l}  = \sigma^2\exp\big(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\big) \frac{\partial g}{\partial l}$.

With simple calculations, I finally get:

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial l} = \sigma^2\exp\big(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\big) \frac{(x-x')^T(x-x')}{l^3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is also an error in the gradient formulation, because in Rasmussen&Williams - Gaussian Process for Machine Learning, p.114, eq 5.9, it is expressed as:

[Partial deivatives log marginal likelihood w.r.t. hyperparameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI75n.jpg)

where the 2 terms have different signs and the y targets vector is transposed just the first time.