# Gradient of gaussian process marginal likelihood with automatic relevance detection

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, machine-learning

This is a follow up question to: [Gradients of marginal likelihood of Gaussian Process with squared exponential covariance, for learning hyper-parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030534/gradients-of-marginal-likelihood-of-gaussian-process-with-squared-exponential-co).

Given a covariance function:

$K(x,x') = \sigma^2\exp\big(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\big)$

The gradient with respect to $l$ is:

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial l} = \sigma^2\exp\big(\frac{-(x-x')^T(x-x')}{2l^2}\big) \frac{(x-x')^T(x-x')}{l^3}$

Assuming $x$ and $x'$ are vectors of length $m$, $l$ can be made into a vector of length $m$ and the relevance of each element in $x$ can be learned (automatic relevance determination). My question is if $l$ is a vector how is the gradient for each $l_{i}$ calculated? It may be obvious but I am getting confused by the matrix calculus notation and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problem so i'm not sure that my answer is correct. However, making egual to zero the partial derivatives (gradient) of ***the negative log marginal likelihood (nlml)*** you obtain such a step and a direction to change iteratively the value of hyperparameters. Your iteration ends when you minimize the ***nlml*** to an enough small value (so actually an high value because ***nlml*** is already negative). Finally to answer your question ***l*** is just the vector of its values, as you can find in Rasmussen&Williams:

[Rasmussen&Williams- Gaussian process for machine learning - ch. 5.1, p.106](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUamW.jpg)